# geography queries in T-SQL: using indexes

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlgeography

Let's say we have a database of Birthday Clowns that contains a geography column containing the binary representation of a Point where each clown is located (generated from the latitude and longitude of the clown's home address). There's a geo-index on the geography column.

The CEO of a major international software company sends us a CSV file of all of their employees in the US, and their street addresses, including latitude and longitude; we have to generate a report that says for each employee how many birthday clowns are within 15 miles.

Our where condition could look like this:

```
where 
(ClownLocationInBinary).STDistance( geography::Point(EES.lat, EES.lng, 4326) ) < radius
```

or like this:

```
where
   geography::Point(EES.lat, EES.lng, 4326).STDistance(ClownLocationInBinary) < radius
```

Will both where-clauses take advantage of the index we created on our BirthdayClowns table? Or does one of them use it but not the other? If so, which is which?

Answer (score 0):

When I asked yesterday, I wasn't at a machine with a SQL Server installation and couldn't check the query plan, and couldn't find the info by searching. But I've since had a chance to check out the query plan, and BOTH versions of the where clause use the index.